# Adjust igMap Marker Size

Tags: asp.net-mvc, infragistics, ignite-ui

I am attempting to map out certain data points using ignite UI's igMap control. What I want to happen is based on the larger realized rate per hour, make the map marker larger or smaller. The documentation through infragistics doesn't seem to go into this very much, so if anyone has an input, I'd appreciate it

```
@model IEnumerable<OpsOverallGeoMapViewModel>

<style>
#tooltipTable {
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

    #tooltipTable td, #tooltipTable th {
        font-size: 9px;
        border: 1px solid #28b51c;
        padding: 3px 7px 2px 7px;
    }

    #tooltipTable th {
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 11px;
        text-align: left;
        padding-top: 5px;
        padding-bottom: 4px;
        background-color: #28b51c;
        color: #ffffff;
    }
</style>
<script id="tooltipTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
<table id="tooltipTable">
    <tr><th class="tooltipHeading" colspan="2">${item.Country}</th></tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Total Hours:</td>
        <td>${item.Hours}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Total Billing:</td>
        <td>${item.Billing}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Realized Rate Per Hour:</td>
        <td>${item.RealizedRatePerHour}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</script>


<div id="map"></div>

<script>

    $(function () {


        var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));

        $("#map").igMap({
            width: "700px",
            height: "500px",
            windowRect: { left: 0.225, top: 0.1, height: 0.6, width: 0.6 },
            series: [{
                type: "geographicSymbol",
                name: "worldCities",
                dataSource: model, //JSON Array defined above
                latitudeMemberPath: "Latitude",
                longitudeMemberPath: "Longitude",
                markerType: "automatic",
                markerOutline: "#28b51c",
                markerBrush: "#28b51c",
                showTooltip: true,
                tooltipTemplate: "tooltipTemplate"

            }],

        });
    });
</script>


<div id="map"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out by running through the example for marker templates on infragistics website. By changing the circle radius of the marker, it makes this into a sort of heat map which is what I was looking for

```
$(function () {


    var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.OrderBy(x => x.Billing)));

    $("#map").igMap({
        width: "700px",
        height: "500px",
        windowRect: { left: 0.1, top: 0.1, height: 0.7, width: 0.7 },
        // specifies imagery tiles from BingMaps
        backgroundContent: {
            type: "bing",
            key: "Masked Purposely",
            imagerySet: "Road", // alternative: "Road" | "Aerial"
        },
        series: [{
            type: "geographicSymbol",
            name: "ratesGraph",
            dataSource: model, //JSON Array defined above
            latitudeMemberPath: "Latitude",
            longitudeMemberPath: "Longitude",
            markerType: "automatic",
            markerCollisionAvoidance: "fade",
            markerOutline: "#1142a6",
            markerBrush: "#7197e5",
            showTooltip: true,
            tooltipTemplate: "customTooltip",
            //  Defines marker template rendering function
            markerTemplate: {
                measure: function (measureInfo) {
                    measureInfo.width = 10;
                    measureInfo.height = 10;
                },
                render: function (renderInfo) {
                    createMarker(renderInfo);
                }
            }

        }]

    });
});




function createMarker(renderInfo) {
    var ctx = renderInfo.context;
    var x = renderInfo.xPosition;
    var y = renderInfo.yPosition;
    var size = 10;
    var heightHalf = size / 2.0;
    var widthHalf = size / 2.0;
    if (renderInfo.isHitTestRender) {
        //  This is called for tooltip hit test only
        //  Rough marker rectangle size calculation
        ctx.fillStyle = renderInfo.data.actualItemBrush().fill();
        ctx.fillRect(x - widthHalf, y - heightHalf, size, size);
    } else {
        var data = renderInfo.data;
        var name = data.item()["CountryName"];
        var type = data.item()["Country"];
        var billing = data.item()["Billing"];
        //  Draw text
        ctx.textBaseline = "top";
        ctx.font = '8pt Verdana';
        ctx.fillStyle = "black";
        ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
        wrapText(ctx, name, x + 3, y + 6, 80, 12);

        //  Draw marker
        ctx.beginPath();
        //SET THE CIRCLE RADIUS HERE*******
        var circleRadius = 3;
        var radiusFactor = billing / 100000;
        if (radiusFactor > 4)
            circleRadius = radiusFactor;
        if (circleRadius > 10)
            circleRadius = 10;
        ctx.arc(x, y,circleRadius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);



        ctx.fillStyle = "#36a815";

        ctx.fill();
        ctx.lineWidth = 1;
        ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
        ctx.stroke();
    }
}

//  Plots a rectangle with rounded corners with a semi-transparent frame
function plotTextBackground(context, left, top, width, height) {
    var cornerRadius = 3;
    context.beginPath();
    //  Upper side and upper right corner
    context.moveTo(left + cornerRadius, top);
    context.lineTo(left + width - cornerRadius, top);
    context.arcTo(left + width, top, left + width, top + cornerRadius, cornerRadius);
    //  Right side and lower right corner
    context.lineTo(left + width, top + height - cornerRadius);
    context.arcTo(left + width, top + height, left + width - cornerRadius, top + height, cornerRadius);
    //  Lower side and lower left corner
    context.lineTo(left + cornerRadius, top + height);
    context.arcTo(left, top + height, left, top + height - cornerRadius, cornerRadius);
    //  Left side and upper left corner
    context.lineTo(left, top + cornerRadius);
    context.arcTo(left, top, left + cornerRadius, top, cornerRadius);
    //  Fill white with 75% opacity
    context.globalAlpha = 1;
    context.fillStyle = "white";
    context.fill();
    context.globalAlpha = 1;
    //  Plot grey frame
    context.lineWidth = 1;
    context.strokeStyle = "grey";
    context.stroke();
}

//  Outputs text in a word wrapped fashion in a transparent frame
function wrapText(context, text, x, y, maxWidth, lineHeight) {
    var words = text.split(" ");
    var line = "";
    var yCurrent = y;
    var lines = [], currentLine = 0;

    //  Find the longest word in the text and update the max width if the longest word cannot fit
    for (var i = 0; n < words.length; i++) {
        var testWidth = context.measureText(words[i]);
        if (testWidth > maxWidth)
            maxWidth = metrics.width;
    }
    //  Arrange all words into lines
    for (var n = 0; n < words.length; n++) {
        var testLine = line + words[n];
        var testWidth = context.measureText(testLine).width;
        if (testWidth > maxWidth) {
            lines[currentLine] = line;
            currentLine++;
            line = words[n] + " ";
        }
        else {
            line = testLine + " ";
        }
    }
    lines[currentLine] = line;
    //  Plot frame and background
    if (lines.length > 1) {
        //  Multiline text
        plotTextBackground(context, x - 2, y - lineHeight / 2 - 2, maxWidth + 3, lines.length * lineHeight + 3);
    }
    else {
        //  Single line text
        var textWidth = context.measureText(lines[0]).width;    //  Limit frame width to the actual line width
        plotTextBackground(context, x - 2, y - lineHeight / 2 - 2, textWidth + 3, lines.length * lineHeight + 3);
    }
    //  Output lines of text
    context.fillStyle = "black";
    for (var n = 0; n < lines.length; n++) {
        context.fillText(" " + lines[n], x, yCurrent);
        yCurrent += lineHeight;
    }
}
```